# How to track which radio button was selected on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics

I'm currently setting up some GA tracking on a form which contains 6 radio buttons. I'd like to be able to send the event tracking to GA when the form is submitted.

I currently have

```
    $(function() {
    $('.className').change(function(){
      if($("input:#radiobutton1").is(":checked")){
          ga("send", "event", "category", "action", "label")
      }
    });
    $('.className').change(function(){
      if($("input:#radiobutton2").is(":checked")){
          ga("send", "event", "category", "action", "label")
      }
    });
    $('.className').change(function(){
        if($("input:#radiobutton3").is(":checked")){
            ga("send", "event", "category", "action", "label")
        }
      });
    $('.className').change(function(){
    if($("input:#radiobutton4").is(":checked")){
        ga("send", "event", "category", "action", "label")
    }
    });
    $('.className').change(function(){
    if($("input:#radiobutton5").is(":checked")){
        ga("send", "event", "category", "action", "label")
    }
    });
    $('.className').change(function(){
    if($("input:#radiobutton6").is(":checked")){
        ga("send", "event", "category", "action", "label")
    }
    });
  });


<form action="/" class="className" id="idName" method="post" name="name">


<fieldset id="start">

<label for="Option1">
<p><input type="radio" name="Methods" id="radiobutton1" value="1" onclick="OptionRadSelect(1, 'one');" data-option="one">Option 1<a href="/one" class="btn" rel="option" style="display: none;"></a></p></label>
<label for="Option2">
<p><input type="radio" name="Methods" id="radiobutton2" value="2" onclick="OptionRadSelect(2, 'two');" data-option="two">Option 2<a href="/two" class="btn" rel="option" style="display: none;"></a></p></label>
<label for="Option3">
<p><input type="radio" name="Methods" id="radiobutton3" value="3" onclick="OptionRadSelect(3, 'three');" data-option="three">Option 3<a href="/three" class="btn" rel="option" style="display: none;"></a></p></label>
<label for="Option4">
<p><input type="radio" name="Methods" id="radiobutton4" value="4" onclick="OptionRadSelect(4, 'four');" data-option="four">Option 4<a href="/four" class="btn" rel="option" style="display: none;"></a></p></label>
<label for="Option5">
<p><input type="radio" name="Methods" id="radiobutton5" value="5" onclick="OptionRadSelect(5, 'five');" data-option="five">Option 5<a href="/six" class="btn" rel="option" style="display: none;"></a></p></label>
<label for="Option6">
<p><input type="radio" name="Methods" id="radiobutton6" value="6" onclick="OptionRadSelect(6, 'six');" data-option="six">Option 6<a href="/seven" class="btn" rel="option" style="display: none;"></a></p></label>

</fieldset>

   <div class="proceed row-fluid" data-bind="click: submitForm"">
<a class="proceed btn active green" data-bind="text: $root.quickstart() ? $root.startOption().quickBtnText : $root.startOption().btnText, css: $root.startOption().btnClass" href="javascript:;">Submit</a>
</div>

</form>
```

This works ok, in that it sends the event off to GA...but it will send more than one event, if a user selects a radio button then changes their mind.

I was thinking maybe one way of only sending one event to GA would be to send it on submit of the form?

Any help on this appreciated.

Thanks

Edit to add: The submit button doesnt have input type="submit" and I cant access the html

Comment: dont you just want to use this `$('.className').submit(function()`?

Comment: Show us your HTML code too.

Comment: Will you make sure that your radio buttons have the same name? If no, they won't treat as the same group, and once you select a radio button others will not be automatically deselected.

Comment: Yes, all the radio buttons will have the same name. Thanks

Comment: @RamondeVries That would work, but.... My submit button doesnt have input type-submit and I cant get to the html to change it.

Comment: You don't need to have an input submit button.  You only need to perform the submit in some way, such as Ramon de Vries says, a jQuery submit will work, but since I didn't see what the ga function does, it may be that you're using Ajax and not actually submitting the form, so leaving it able to accept user input over and over, again.  Perhaps you could include the ga function?